# Rails Paperclip content_type validation error after convert & display wrong error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a problem with the validation of the content type by the Paperclip plug-in:

image.rb (relevant extract)

```
  has_attached_file :photo,
    :styles => {:xlarge => "640x512>", :large => "350x280>", :medium => "180x144^",
                :thumb => "100x80^", :original => "1280x1280>" },
    :convert_options => {:xlarge => "-strip", :large => "-strip",
                :medium => "-strip -gravity center -extent 180x144 +repage",
                :thumb => "-strip -gravity center -extent 100x80 +repage"},
    :default_style => :medium,
    :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:basename_:id_:style.:extension"


  validates_attachment_presence :photo
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/x-png', 'image/jpeg2000'], :message => 'Uploaded file is not an image'
```

I'm using nested forms, the image model is the child model of the property model.
During testing the validations of my form I come across some problems. I'm testing validations by uploading a PDF file where the model accepts only images.

output in my form view of: <%= @property.errors.inspect %>

```
#[#, @message="Uploaded file is not an image">], 
"images.photo"=>[#, @message="C:/Users/Michael/AppData/Local/Temp/stream,4272,1.pdf is not recognized by the 'identify' command.">]}>, @base=#>
```

output in the view of the validation error(s) on the file upload input box:

```
C:/Users/Michael/AppData/Local/Temp/stream,4272,1.pdf is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
C:/Users/Michael/AppData/Local/Temp/stream,4272,1.pdf is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
C:/Users/Michael/AppData/Local/Temp/stream,4272,1.pdf is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
C:/Users/Michael/AppData/Local/Temp/stream,4272,1.pdf is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
C:/Users/Michael/AppData/Local/Temp/stream,4272,1.pdf is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
```

**2 issues:**

**issue 1**

The input field shows 5 times the same error, that is because I have 5 styles set up in the model. Question is, why does paperclip try to identify (and probably convert the pdf), when you would expect the validation to run first and return already an error before trying to identify and convert? Does Paperclip convert to all the styles before running validations? If yes, is there a way to switch the order of processing, first validation, then styles processing?

**issue 2**

How can I display the error message of the validation ('Uploaded file is not an image') next to the file upload input box instead of the erros now displayed (5 x the output of the identify command), the latter is of no use to the website user.

Thanks!

Comment: I started using the plugin in stead of the gem. It seems to me that Paperclip doesn't correclty handle errors if the image model is used as a child model in a nested models form.

I'm gonna try Carrierwave as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I have used

has_attached_file :photo, :whiny => false

and this seems to have helped the error messages.  For the error messages, I was using

OBJECT.errors[:photo_content_type]
OBJECT.errors[:photo_file_size]

Comment: I just checked, I'm not sure anymore what I did to correct it, the error message is ok now, even without using the whiny option. But still my implementation in quite buggy, I want to redo everything with Carrierwave.